# What's happen with my kinect?[img included]

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

image:[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12446150/wrong_kinect.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12446150/wrong_kinect.png)
I just downloaded openni_kinect and try to get depth image.

But it looks weird.

Is this right?

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9996/what%27s-happen-with-my-kinect?%5Bimg-included%5D/) by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 177 on 2011-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz seems to interpret the 16 (or 14?) bit depth as 8 bit gray value. Therefore you have an "overflow" at each 256 depth-steps, causing the value to cycle between black and white several times. I wonder why it's not getting really white, but that could either be the alpha of 0.5 in rviz or a confusion between signed and unsigned char.

Does the pointcloud look normal?

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-05-19**:
Bingo!  I ran into this as well.  I didn't really want to mess with fixing rviz, so I just used point clouds.